# How to run multiple async functions in order they were called (FIFO?)

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-async

I've spent many hours looking for the solution, but since I am Dart begginer, I couldn't find it out by myself.
What I want to achieve is to create something like queue for some of the async functions that are called randomly (let's say, when user is tapping a button in my app) from different points in code while the app is running. I want them to be executed in the order they were called, so basically I have async methods such as **updateDate()** and **updatePoints()** and when the user is tapping button X the updateDate() is going to be called (added to queue), and similar with Y and updatePoints(). When the user taps i. e. X, X, Y I want to run updateDate(), updateDate(), updatePoints() in this exact order. When one task is complete, another one is starting. I guess I can't use await to achieve that. Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: if everything must be sync why use async? but you could try this... doSomethingAsync().then((_) => doAnotherAsync()); I'm not sure how many levels deep this will work

Comment: @stuckedoverflow well, if everything was sync, there would be no problem.

Comment: see [forEachAsync](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/quiver.async/forEachAsync.html) - the docs say: *"Schedules calls to action for each element in iterable. No more than maxTasks calls to action will be pending at once."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:collection';
import 'dart:math';

Future<void> main() async {
  _simulateRealWork();
}

Scheduler _scheduler = Scheduler();

class Scheduler {
  bool _scheduled = false;

  Queue<Future Function()> _queue = Queue<Future Function()>();

  void schedule(Future Function() task) {
    _queue.add(task);
    if (!_scheduled) {
      _scheduled = true;
      Timer(Duration(seconds: 0), _execute);
    }
  }

  Future _execute() async {
    while (true) {
      if (_queue.isEmpty) {
        _scheduled = false;
        return;
      }

      var first = _queue.removeFirst();
      await first();
    }
  }
}

void _simulateRealWork() {
  var maxPeriod = 5;
  var count = 5;
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    print('Timer $i');
    var random = Random();
    Timer(Duration(seconds: random.nextInt(maxPeriod)), () {
      print('Scheduled work $i');
      Future work() async {
        print('Started work $i');
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: random.nextInt(maxPeriod)));
        print('Ended work $i');
      }

      _scheduler.schedule(work);
    });
  }
}
```

Result:

`Timer 0
Timer 1
Timer 2
Timer 3
Timer 4
Scheduled work 2
Started work 2
Scheduled work 0
Scheduled work 3
Ended work 2
Started work 0
Scheduled work 1
Scheduled work 4
Ended work 0
Started work 3
Ended work 3
Started work 1
Ended work 1
Started work 4
Ended work 4`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That's exactly what I was looking for. I guess I was pretty close though.

Answer (score 2):

The following code might be a bad practice when used in large queue of tasks, but if you are sure that the array of tasks won't exceed an adequate size - this might work just fine:

```dart
Future<List<T>> runOneByOne<T>(List<T Function()> list) {
  if (list.isEmpty) {
    return Future.value(null);
  }
  Future task = Future<T>.microtask(list.first);
  final List<T> results = [];

  for (var i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
    final func = list[i];
    task = task.then((res) { results.add(res); return Future<T>.microtask(func); });
  }

  return task.then((res) { results.add(res); return results; });
}
```

It executes functions one-by-one in the original order by wrapping one `Future` into another. `results` array is used to store returned values, returning all of the values in the end.

Execution stops and throws if stumbled upon an error. Results array is lost in that case. You can add `try {...}` closure to every `microtask` wrapper to ignore errors and return `null` in that one particular task, preserving other values in `results` array.

Usage example:

```dart
runOneByOne<int>([
  () { print("First"); return 1; },
  () { print("Second"); return 2; },
  () { print("Third"); return 3; },
]).then((results) {
  print(results); // List<int> [ 1, 2, 3 ]
});
```